# Angular2 - Can't bind to 'ngModel' not a known property

Tags: angular

In my @ngModule I have the imports FormsModule and ReactiveFOrmsModule.
But I am still getting the following error:

```
zone.js?1477571032896:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'p-editor'.
1. If 'p-editor' is an Angular component and it has 'ngModel' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'p-editor' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

</p-editor>"): MainComponent@2:40
No provider for NgControl ("

[ERROR ->]<p-editor formControlName="description" [(ngModel)]="text" (onTextChange)="onTextChange($event)" [sty"): MainComponent@2:0
```

This is also happening on normal things like inputs if I try to bind using the [(ngModel)]

This is the html:

```
<p-editor formControlName="description" [(ngModel)]="text" (onTextChange)="onTextChange($event)" [style]="{'height':'200px'}">
```

This is the guide I am using: It works fine without hte [(ngModel)]

```
http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/editor
```

My app.module.ts

```
imports: [
              BrowserModule,
              FormsModule,
              ReactiveFormsModule,
```

In the main components module:

```
import { EditorModule, SharedModule, ButtonModule, TabMenuModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
```

And they are added to the imports

Comment: please add NgModule code.

Comment: Did you add the primeng module to your `@NgModule`

Comment: You need to add `FormsModule` to the imports of your current `@NgModule(...)`.

Answer (score 4):

Just add FormsModule in your app.module.ts file like below it worked for me hope it works for you too

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
declarations: [ AppComponent ],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add *ngModelOptions* attribute in addition to *ngModel*

```
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
```

Comment: I am getting the same error.